# PHP Class resolve issue for classes in the same directory when running PHPUnit test cases

Tags: php, phpunit, classloader

I installed PHPUnit and my Test class looks like this:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';

class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {...}
```

When I execute the PHP script in Eclipse, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_Assert' not found in .../PEAR/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 99

So I created a general PHP classloading test:

- A.php and B.php in the same directory

A.php:

```
class AA {}
```

B.php:

```
class BB extends AA {}
new BB();
```

When executing the PHP script B.php I get the same error:

> Fatal error: Class 'AA' not found in .../B.php on line 2

There must be an option for PHP to be able to resolve these classes otherwise PHPUnit could not work. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you execute the tests? PHPUnit is a commandline tool. When you use it like that, it will install its own autoloader, so usually you dont have to require anything as long as PEAR is in your include_path. When you run it from Eclipse, make sure you "Run as PHPUnit Test" and not just as a script.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I figured that out a while after I posted my question here. :)

Comment: want me to post it as answer so you can accept it as the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be loading / require

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';
```

in your tests at all. The normal phpunit runner should be able to figure that out.

Usually IDEs *should* care about setting phpunit up properly (or invoking it properly) but if that doesn't work out requiring

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

That should do the trick then as this is whats needed to make PHPUnit working

Comment: Thank you. There is a PHPUnit extension for PTI but this one does not work on my Eclipse for some reason. However, I will just use the command line phpunit.

Comment: Maybe that has to do with PHPUnit 3.6. From what I've seen PTI usually works quite well :)  --- Anyways: If your issue is solved please mark one of the answers as "accepted" (checkmark text to one of the answers) to let people know your problem is solved and that they can look at another question.

Comment: I think one of the reasons for this is the fact that one of the first exercises in the PHPUnit handbook instructs you to do that. Then you run into this error and end up on the stack overflow page (this is how I found it BTW).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when integrating with NetBeans.  The solution for me was to load a bootstrap.php file, which would include all necessary dependencies while leaving my class files untouched.

**Oops**: just realized you're using Eclipse.  It should be pretty similar.  The problem is likely that your include script is relative to Eclipse's working directory (or some directory other than where you application normally runs).  But that's a stab in the dark without being too familiar with Eclipse myself...

Answer (score 0):

In case PHPUnit 6.x is used, then `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` class has been removed. You should use namespaces instead, or downgrade to `~4.5`.

So replace `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` with `\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert`, ot use statement like:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;
```

And use Assert directly, e.g. `Assert::assertNotEmpty(...);`.

<sup>Source: [Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_Assert' not found (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError #2585](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2585)</sup>